# How to monitor multiple ports with blackbox exporter?

Tags: monitoring

I'm using Prometheus and I need to monitor multiple ports, but I couldn't find information about that. Blackbox exporter docs aren't enough because that only pertains to monitoring one port.

I'm using Ubuntu Server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the port in the list of targets. Take the official example:

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'blackbox'
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [http_2xx]  # Look for a HTTP 200 response.
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://prometheus.io    # Target to probe with http.
        - https://prometheus.io   # Target to probe with https.
        - http://example.com:8080 # Target to probe with http on port 8080.
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: 127.0.0.1:9115  # Blackbox exporter.
```

You can just specify one target for each port like:

```
    static_configs:
      - targets:
        - http://example.com:1234
        - http://example.com:4567
        - http://example.com:8901
```

This example uses the http_2xx probe, but same applies to other probe modules too.